# Changing jQuery Div Hover Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery code that works like so... When you hover over a block, a new div slides up and a red block div fades out, then when you leave the hover area the div then slides back down and the red block div fades back in. Everything works fine, here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gsghr/119/

The only problem is when the new div slides up that says "the first item needs to toggle up", the div should stay in its place if your mouse hovers over that div.  Instead, as soon as your mouse leaves the div area for the "item 1" grey block div, the other div (that says "the first item needs to toggle up") will disappear.

I tried changing the hover area for the divs via CSS like so, but it did not work...

```
#coltab li:hover + #coltab ul li, #coltab ul li:hover {
display: block;
}
```

Maybe I was doing that wrong.  But again, it should work so when you hover over the div that says "the first item needs to toggle up". that div should stay in its place and not slide back down.  Again, here is the jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Gsghr/119/ and any help would be appreciated. :)

*Also if you hover over the divs multiple times in a row there is jumping and the whole function of the hover might even mess up, if anyone could fix that or has an explanation for it that would be awesome.*

Answer (score 1):

Change the z-order of the div you want to stay up so that it's higher than the red div.  If that's not visually desirable then try using an invisible div with a higher z-order that matches the same size of the div you want to stay up.

The jumping is just coming from how many times the hover is called.  I don't know the exact answer to this question but I imagine you can use "undelegate" to keep the events from stacking.

Comment: i also tried changing the z-index's, if thats what you mean. A jsfiddle would be nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also a recent Jquery enthusiast, but I suggest using mouseenter and mouseleave methods.
The mouseleave method will not let the event get down to the child level, and hope that should do the trick.

Check the example demo here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Tc, Amit

Comment: thanks Amit. Unfortunately, I do not know how to apply this method to my current code. If you could apply this to my jsfiddle that would be amazing! :)